# Modem hang-up time

Tags: serial, modem

I'm looking for some typical and worst-case times for a serial modem to hang up and DCD deassert after receiving the hang-up command string ("ATH").

My project uses a modem and occasionally must reboot for other reasons.  The reboot is fast enough that if I don't wait after sending ATH, DCD is frequently still asserted when the system comes back up and it tries sending application messages to the modem while the previous connection finishes closing.

I can easily wait for DCD to deassert before closing down, but don't want to get stuck in an infinite loop if something goes wrong.  How soon should I be able to expect a serial modem to close a connection?  After how long can I suppose that something is wrong if DCD is still high after sending a hang-up command?

Comment: A link to the modem in question would help. Serial modems are of various types, with various reasonable time-outs. For instance, a RF Line-of-Sight point-to-point spread spectrum serial modem from the late '90s such as those by RAD Network Devices, is typically configured for 10 to 45 second handshakes and hand-offs, longer if in a point-to-multipoint mesh.

Comment: I don't have a specific modem.  I'm not even developing with a real modem.  It could be used with any RS-232 modem.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any modem with this specified.  They all mention connection time, but no one is specifying their hang-up time.

Comment: There may not be a specified "hang up time", but depending on the type of modem, the media and the protocol(s), there will be best practices defined for time-out for hang-up. Also, some modems allow an ATH0 time-out to be user-defined, so your design's time-out should match or exceed that setting.

Comment: I don't know if all (other then serial telephone) modems support it, but it might be worth to see if a DTR hangup works better. Meaning that the modem follows the DTR signal, drop the DTR line and the line is instantly dropped as well. You must configure a modem to actually do this.

Comment: Worst-case would be something crashing, so effectively forever. Realistically, it's "Until the user gets annoyed enough he force-kills the application".

Comment: I've seen serial timeouts as long as 60 seconds in some Linux software that's currently available (e.g. in the ubuntu repositories).

Comment: How fast does you project reboot?  In my experience, modems always disconnected "way too fast" after losing carrier.  I'm having difficulty imagining you can beat the modem.  Maybe it does disconnect and it just takes longer for DCD to go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions occur to me:

1. Not knowing the exact worst case, use a generous timeout, like one second. After rebooting, do not do anything with the modem for that long. (Perhaps conditionally: do not do anything with the modem for one second *while it is asserting DCD*. If it is not asserting DCD, then just proceed, and also bail out of the loop the moment it stops asserting DCD.
2. Refinement: in some nonvolatile storage which survives reboots, record a flag which says "there is a modem hang-up transaction in progress". Always clear the flag when the modem finishes hanging up. If a reboot happens during a hangup, then upon reboot, if you find this flag, then you know that if the modem is asserting DCD, this is not a valid modem session, but one that is in process of hanging up. The software must wait for DCD to go away. In this (presumably infrequent) case, you can perhaps tolerate a more generous delay.

The delay does not have to affect the full boot sequence, just the startup of the application which communicates with the modem.

Comment: Right.  It's not even the whole device that reboots, just communications.  In the meantime, I've set a wait bailout time of 2 seconds.  But this is just a gut, "I can't imagine it taking that long" type of magic number, and I would rather have some evidential support in my documentation of the choice of my length.